# Is this a correct way to use transistors as an LED "switchback" circuit?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, led, switches, bjt

I'm not a confident electronics degisner/user so I'd like to check with a knowledgeable community if this cuircuit would be safe and correct to use and if there's a way that extra protection should be implemented.

Its purpose is very similar to what you might see on cars with bright LED daytime running lights - when they indicate and it's flashing, the same side DRL gets dimmed or shut off in order to make the indicator more conspicuous.

The LED in my case is the DRL and is powered by a +12 V signal from either the "button" or the "bypass". (Ignore the disconnected "button", that is just to illustrate why the diode D1 is for, to isolate the two inputs.)

As is sits now - the circuit seems to be working fine, power is provided by "bypass" and LED is lit.

[image]

Going further, in my case there's a signal wire that gets grounded (permanently, not flashing-dependent) whenever an indicator is activated. The circle points at a disconnected ground to represent that.

When I connect the ground in the simulation, it seems to do what I want, by using the BJT to pull the gate of the N-MOSFET to ground and turn it off, thus the LED switches off.

My questions are:
Are the resistor values correct?
Do I even need the R7 resistor?
What safety features should I add?
And is the circuit as a whole ...well...acceptable?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Why are the lost connections in your schematic?

Comment: Why bother with R5, R7 & Q1 at all? Why not just ground the right-hand side of R3 directly (thru whatever mechanism is represented by the red circle)?

Comment: It needs to switch LED off when that wire is grounded.